# How to forward unregistered email to a registered email

Tags: google-apps-email

I have bought Google email services and pointed my GoDaddy's MX records to Google and I was able to create users via admin.google.com.

I dont know how to explain this, but lets say I want email named `info@example.com` or `contact@example.com` to be forwarded to `admin@example.com`. I dont want to add a additional users for `info` and `contact`.

The feature is there in GoDaddy, but as I have changed the MX record to Google, the email forwarding in GoDaddy is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific names can be added as "aliases" under *Users → admin → Account*.

A global catch-all address can be configured under *Google Apps → Gmail → Advanced → Routing*.